# How do I import a Microstation cell library as symbology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, microstation

I have a .cel file with (point) symbols. I want to import that as symbology in QGIS. QGIS accepts xml files for that. How do I either change the .cel file to xml? Or is there another way to import the symbols in QGIS?

Comment: you can convert dxf https://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/15106/how-to-convert-all-of-the-cells-in-a-cell-library-to-autocad-dwg-blocks there maybe more work if your symbols are complex